# Wrong email password

Tags: php

The  "Wrong Email and Password" message doesn't show up when I incorrectly fill out the form.

I have `ob_start();` in the beginning of my code - does this cause anything? If I erase `ob_start();`, I have errors of:

> Cannot modify header information

How do I fix this?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $email = $password = $error = "";
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    if (empty($email) || empty($password)) {
        $error = "Please enter your Email and Password!";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE email='$email' && password='$password'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $user = mysql_num_rows($res);

        if ($user['blocked'] == 'YES') {
            $error = "Your Account has been blocked. Please contact us for more info";
        } else {
            if ($user == 1) {
                $_SESSION['current_user'] = $email;
                header("Location: edit_profile.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                $error = "Wrong Email and Password";
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: So, where do you `echo $error;` or how did you get to conclusion that it;s not showing?

Comment: `$user = mysql_num_rows($res);

        if ($user['blocked'] == 'YES') {` that's failing you.

Comment: If this code is to go live on the web, **stop right there**. It's totally unsafe and there are a lot of scripts out there that already exist. This isn't a game.

Answer (score 0):

`ob_start()` turns on output buffering; nothing will display to the screen until you expressly retrieve the contents of the output buffer and stop buffering (e.g., with [`ob_end_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) or a similar function). You haven't done that, so you don't get any output, even though you used `echo`.

You need to tweak that `if`/`else` block like this:

```
        if ($user == 1) {
            $_SESSION['current_user'] = $email;
            header("Location: edit_profile.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            ob_end_clean(); // add this line
            $error = "Wrong Email and Password";
        }
```

Also, your code has several big problems:

- Please [don't use `mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.
- You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Right now, it's trivial to log in as the admin, even without proper permissions.
- You're using the insecure and broken MD5 to hash your passwords. Don't do this. Use a safe and modern library like bcrypt.

Comment: php should automatically flush anything left in the buffer at the end of php execution.

Comment: Assuming OP's code doesn't crash in some way later or simply dispose of the buffer contents...

Comment: so i have to add ob_end_clean()?

I am aware of the mysql_* functions, thanks for pointing it out!